# Django 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable after passing user context in context processor

Tags: django

I need to show few user info in my nav bar such as number of notification, user name etc. So I am passing context in my context processor. My nav bar located in my base.htm and I am extending my base.html in my all html page. I am getting this error if user isn't login `'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable`.here is my code:

**settings.py**

```
 'context_processors': 
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'notifications.views.Count_Notifications', #passing context from notifications app
```

**views.py**

```
def Count_Notifications(request):
    count_notifications_comment = 0
    count_notifications_author = 0
    blog_author = Blog.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        count_notifications_comment = Notifications.objects.filter(sender=request.user,is_seen=False).count()
        count_notifications_author = Notifications.objects.filter(user=request.user,is_seen_author_noti=False).count()
    return {'count_notifications_comment':count_notifications_comment,'count_notifications_author':count_notifications_author,'blog_author':blog_author}
```

**console error:**

```
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot assign "False": "Notifications.user" must be a "User" instance.
[17/Jul/2021 02:18:08] "POST /admin/blog/blog/26/change/ HTTP/1.1" 500 160786
```

Comment: Please show the full stack trace.

Comment: Code-Apprentice getting this error `'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable` if user is unauthenticated . I am new in django. what do you mean by full stack trace???

Comment: Where do you see this error? You may see it rendered in the browser if you have `DEBUG=True`. This is a fancy version of teh stack trace. For a plan-text version of the same information, go to the terminal where you have `./manage runserver` running and copy/paste that output into your question here.

Comment: yes it  it rendered in the browser

Comment: Code-Apprentice in my terminal I am seeing this error `TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable`

Comment: After the `./manage.py runserver` command you should see several lines that start with `GET` or `POST`. Each of these are a log of each request made to your Django app. If there is an error, you will see a whole bunch of text printed after the request line. Please [edit] your question to include all of that output for the request that causes the error you are asking about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234985/discussion-between-boyenec-and-code-apprentice).

Comment: @boyenec: please share the *full* traceback, copy (all) the text you see on the screen when this error appears, not just the last line.

Comment: `[17/Jul/2021 02:18:08] "POST /admin/blog/blog/26/change/ HTTP/1.1" 500 160786` This line is for the next request, which also fails. You need to copy paste everything from one of these lines up to the next one. This is the stacktrace I was asking for earlier and has all the information that can help you start finding the problem. The error message alone isn't enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the login required decorator above your view so you'll be prompted to connect before being able to access this page

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

```
@login_required
def Count_Notifications(request):
    .....
```

Comment: now getting this error `dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required`